# Concatenated DateTime string isn't passing to sql

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datetime, datetimepicker

I am working on passing a formatted datetime variable to SQL Server. I need to concatenate the date with the time, as they come from 2 different controls. The code seems to work okay and the two strings, once put together, are parsed as DateTime.

The problem is that when it goes up to SQL Server, the time part is lost and the column displays `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff` as `2012-09-03 00:00:00.000` as opposed to `2012-09-03-12 1:23:45:678` (for example).

Here's my code, for testing I have replaced the time with a hard-coded variable, and `objInfo.SemesterEnrollStart` is a `DateTime` variable. Also, the control `dpEnrollStart` is a `DatePicker`.

```
DateTime semDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dpEnrollStart.SelectedDate);
string semTime = "12:34";
DateTime dtp = DateTime.ParseExact(semDate.ToShortDateString() + " " + semTime, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", null);
objInfo.SemesterEnrollStart = dtp;
```

Thanks so much!

EDIT:
So, here's the c# that I am using to call the stored procedure:

```
objInfo.SemesterQuarter =  ddl_SemQuarter.SelectedValue;
objInfo.SemesterYear = ddl_SemYear.SelectedValue;
objInfo.SemesterStart = Convert.ToDateTime(dpSemStart.SelectedDate);
objInfo.SemesterEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(dpSemEnd.SelectedDate);

DateTime semDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dpEnrollStart.SelectedDate);
string semTime = "12:34:00.000";
objInfo.SemesterEnrollStart = DateTime.ParseExact(semDate.ToShortDateString() + " " + semTime, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", null);                                                        

objInfo.SemesterEnrollEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(dpEnrollEnd.SelectedDate);
objInfo.PriorityRegDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dpPriRegDate.SelectedDate);
objInfo.AgeCutoffDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dpAgeCutoffDate.SelectedDate);
lblTSMessage.Text = objInfo.SemesterEnrollStart.ToString();
objManager.AddNewSemester(objInfo);
```

Comment: Could you provide move detail around "when it goes up to SQL"?  Are you running a query? Calling a stored procedure?  What is `objInfo`?

Comment: Is your sql datatype a `smalldatetime` or just a `Date`? That will cause it to not store with a time. (Or it's set to 12:00:00 I think...)

Comment: Thanks guys, I am running a SQL stored procedure non-query.  It is inserting the DateTime.  The SQL column is a datetime.  objInfo is the object which holds the variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the format you are using in ParseExact:

```
 MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm
```

Therefore, you are purposely discarding the seconds and milliseconds part.

Instead, you need to parse your date with: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff` but then you will need to capture `seconds` (ss) and `milliseconds`(fff) in the semTime variable or the `ParseExact` method will crap out.

One Example:

```
string s = "01/01/2012 11:23";
//FAILS because there's not ss and fff part 
DateTime dtp = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff", null);

string s = "01/01/2012 11:23:12.678";
//Works because there's a ss and fff part
DateTime dtp = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff", null);
```

Comment: Thanks, Icarus.  Do I still need to format the DateTime for miliseconds and fractions if I am not passing them?  Also, I tried  `DateTime.Parse(semDate.ToShortDateString() + " " + semTime)` Which output correctly (seemingly), but the time was still not recognized by sql

Comment: @LucasSmith the problem is that if you use `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff` and you don't provide ss and fff then ParseExact throws an error. So in instances where you don't have a `ss` and `fff` part, you must pass `0` as defaults. You can verify that the date parsed does indeed contain the seconds and milliseconds you passed in: `Console.WriteLine(dtp.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff"));` should display everything. Provided an example

Comment: Thanks again @Icarus!  I tried passing some default second, milisecond and fraction values (12:34:00.000) to the ParseExact method `DateTime dtp = DateTime.ParseExact(semDate.ToShortDateString() + " " + semTime, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff", null);` which converts the strings to a valid datetime, but sql is still not recording it correctly.

Comment: @LucasSmith That's very strange. Post the stored procedure code if you can, specially where you declare the parameters that receives. And if you can, post a little bit more of the C# code that you use to call it.

Comment: Here's the stored procedure code:

`@semQuarter NVARCHAR(50),
@semYear NVARCHAR(50),
@startDate DATE,
@endDate DATE,
@enrollStart DATETIME,
@enrollEnd DATE,
@priRegDate DATE,
@ageCutoffDate DATE
AS
INSERT INTO dbo._Semesters
( QuarterId, [Year], StartDate, EndDate, FirstRegDate, LastRegDate, PriorityRegDate, AgeCutoffDate )
VALUES  ( (SELECT ClassQuarterId FROM dbo.allthatdance_ClassQuarters WHERE QuarterName = @semQuarter),
@semYear,
@startDate,
@endDate,
@enrollStart,
@enrollEnd,
@priRegDate,
@ageCutoffDate)`

Comment: If we are talking about only @enrollStart then it's very strange that this isn't working. For all the other parameters, the type is `date`, which does not support hh,mm,ss and much less ms. Now that the proc doesn't seem to be the problem. The issue must be un your c# code. Somewhere in there you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your attention @Icarus.  I posted the stored procedure call.  It is true that the enrollStart is the only DATETIME column needed.